# jquery get method doesn't do anything, but doing it as a form does (java servlet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a file called index.jsp which is where a user is directed to upon loading my website. 
I want to send a get request to one of my servlets upon loading the page.

So my URL at the beginning is:
localhost:8080/Test/

The servlet will do something when the URL is:
localhost:8080/Test/MyServlet?action=fetchdata

I can get the servlet to perform fetchdata if in the html body i put this:

```
<form name="fetchdata" action="MyServlet" method="get">
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='fetchdata' />
</form>
```

and then run a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.fetchdata.submit();
    var testresult = '${result}';
    document.write(testresult);
</script>
```

However this does not look nice and it is also in the HTML body which seems very unprofessional. So I tried implementing the same function in JQuery by putting this in 
the HTML head:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $.get("MyServlet", { action : "fetchdata"}); 
};
```

and nothing happens when I load the page. I have tested to see that jQuery is working. Any idea on what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Well ya aint doing nothing with that get info

Comment: Well currently my servlet is set to redirect the URL to a completely different webpage, as a test. And I only get redirected using the form method

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("form[name='fetchdata']").trigger('submit');
```

Comment: hi, this does indeed work but it is just a different way of writing my first method. I would like to know what is so different about the get method